# Proof of Equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, functions

I have a question about equicontinuous

> Let $k(x,y)$ be a fixed function of two variables, and continuous on the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ , and let $T$ be a bounded linear operator from $L^2[0,1]$ into itself, defined by $$ Tf(x)  = \int_0^1 k(x,y)f(y)dy.$$ How to prove that if $(f_n)$ satisfies $\left( \int_0^1 \lvert f \rvert^2 \right)^\frac12 \leq 1$ for all $n = 1,2,\dots$ then the set $(Tf_n)$ is equicontinuos.

This is my idea

> Let $\varepsilon$ be given. Choose $\delta=...~~~~~~~~~$. Let $x,y\in [0,1]$ such that $|x-y|\leq\delta$. Then
>   \begin{align*}
> |Tf_n(x)-Tf_n(y)|&=\left|\int_0^1 k(x,t)f(t)dt-\int_0^1 k(y,t)f(t)dt\right|\\
> &\leq \int_0^1 |k(x,t)-k(y,t)||f(t)| dt
> \end{align*}

I have no idea to estimate $ |Tf_n(x)-Tf_n(y)| $. Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$k$ is continuous on the compact set $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, so it is uniformly continuous. Thus for all $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta >0$ so that 
$$ |k(x, t) - k(y, u)| <\epsilon$$
whenever $\sqrt{(x-y)^2 + (t-u)^2} <\delta$. Thus if $|x-y| <\delta$, we have

$$|Tf_n(x) - Tf_n(y)| \le \epsilon \int_0^1 |f_n (t)| dt \le \epsilon \sqrt{\int_0^1 f^2} \le \epsilon.$$

Thus $\{Tf_n\}$ is equicontinuous.